# HTML Vertical scroll on Android doesn't work - Bootstrap + Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome, bootstrap-5

My problem is when I use chrome in my Android, the vertical scroll doesn't works, when I use in Firefox it's works, in desktop works too, any suggestions?

I'm using Bootstrap5 and Angular13.

```
<nav class="sidenav shadow-right" id="sidenavAccordion" [ngClass]="sidenavStyle" data-cy="sideNav">
    <div class="sidenav-menu scrollable">
        <div class="nav">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let section of sideNavSections">
                <div class="sidenav-menu-heading" *ngIf="section.text">{{ section.text }}</div>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of section.items">
                    <sbpro-side-nav-item [sideNavItem]="sideNavItems[item]"></sbpro-side-nav-item>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidenav-footer">
        <div class="sidenav-footer-content" *ngIf="userService.user$ | async as user">
            <div class="sidenav-footer-subtitle">Logado como:</div>
            <div class="sidenav-footer-title">{{user.user.firstName}} {{user.user.lastName}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The Scss code

```
.sidenav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    font-size: 0.9rem;

    .sidenav-menu {
        flex-grow: 1;

        .nav {
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;

            .sidenav-menu-heading {
                padding: 1.75rem 1rem 0.75rem;
                font-size: 0.7rem;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 0.05em;
            }

            .nav-link {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                line-height: normal;
                padding-top: 0.75rem;
                padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
                position: relative;

                .nav-link-icon {
                    font-size: 0.9rem;
                    padding-right: 0.5rem;
                    display: inline-flex;

                    .feather {
                        width: 1rem;
                        height: 1rem;
                    }
                }

                &.active {
                    font-weight: 600;

                    .nav-icon {
                        color: $primary;
                    }
                }

                .sidenav-collapse-arrow {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    transition: transform 0.15s ease;
                }

                &.collapsed {
                    .sidenav-collapse-arrow {
                        transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    }
                }

                .badge {
                    padding: 0.125rem 0.25rem;
                }
            }

            .sidenav-menu-nested {
                flex-direction: column;
                margin-left: 2rem - $sidenav-nested-border-offest;
                border-left-style: solid;
                border-left-width: thin;
                padding-left: $sidenav-nested-border-offest;
            }
        }
    }
```

the interesting thing is that in the browser on the computer everything works, when I go to the smartphone it does not work

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

**Desktop version It's works**

[image: Desktop Version]

Comment: Please add your code to the question, otherwise nobody will be able to help. Thanks!

Comment: Your `<div class="nav">` also needs `overflow-y-auto`